# C# Web API handling of string ID or object property in JSON POST body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to give my API consumers the ability to associate my parent object (shipment) with child object (address) for to: and from:.  I have an /address API where addresses can be created.

I'd like to give my users the ability to create a child address in a shipment post or to reference existing address object id's in the shipment post as well.

Something like this:

```
{
      address_to": {
            "name": "Tom Smith",
            "street1": "111 Maple St",
            "city": "Northport",
            "state": "IL",
            "zip": "60606",
            "country": "US",
        }
      ...
}

or
{
    address_to": "<addressId>"
    ...
}
```

How can I accomplish something like this in a C# .NET Core API Controller?  Here is my controller signature.

```
public virtual IActionResult CreateShipment([FromBody] Shipment inputBody)
{
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, and even if you *could*, you shouldn't. In short, the solution you are attempting to implement *is* the problem.

The `POST` endpoint for orders should create a new order. The `POST` endpoint for addresses should create a new address (from your question, I think this is how your api is currently laid out).

An api is *functional*, providing access to the core functionality required. Combining the two steps is an *implementation* detail, which is not the job of an api.